# Where is the documentation for autogeneration of Has typeclasses in lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I was looking at the penultimate example in this [blog post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern) (also [here](https://github.com/bbarker/ProjectGists/blob/master/Haskell/ReaderLensHas/app/Main.hs)), and after verifying it ran, it seemed to confirm that lens can generate Has typeclasses, which I take was the implication from the author of the blog. However, I miss where this is described, either in the [lens contents](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) or the [lens tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.3/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html). Any explanations external to official docs for how this is done would also be welcome. But it seems like this may just be standard when using the most basic feature (`makeLenses`, or in this case, `makeLensesWith`).

Here is the reproduced code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-8.12 script
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Control.Concurrent.Async.Lifted.Safe
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Say
import Control.Lens
import Prelude hiding (log)

data Env = Env
  { envLog :: !(String -> IO ())
  , envBalance :: !(TVar Int)
  }

makeLensesWith camelCaseFields ''Env

modify :: (MonadReader env m, HasBalance env (TVar Int), MonadIO m)
       => (Int -> Int)
       -> m ()
modify f = do
  env <- ask
  liftIO $ atomically $ modifyTVar' (env^.balance) f

logSomething :: (MonadReader env m, HasLog env (String -> IO ()), MonadIO m)
             => String
             -> m ()
logSomething msg = do
  env <- ask
  liftIO $ (env^.log) msg

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ref <- newTVarIO 4
  let env = Env
        { envLog = sayString
        , envBalance = ref
        }
  runReaderT
    (concurrently
      (modify (+ 1))
      (logSomething "Increasing account balance"))
    env
  balance <- readTVarIO ref
  sayString $ "Final balance: " ++ show balance
```

Comment: You're probably looking for [`makeClassy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeClassy) and friends in the `Control.Lens.TH` docs.

Comment: Interesting, that seems to be the right doc, but am confused on the example above still; `makeLensesWith camelCaseFields` == `makeFieldOptics defaultFieldRules`, which has `_classyLenses    = const Nothing`. On the other hand, `makeClassy` == `makeFieldOptics classyRules`, and `classyRules` has `_classyLenses` set to something more that obviously has an effect on generating `Has` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Field` is the word `lens` uses to describe the pattern of one class per named field, allowing multiple records with the same field name but (optionally) different types.  So `camelCaseFields`, `makeFieldOptics`, `defaultFieldRules` all say in their name that they will generate these `HasFoo` classes, in the usual terse style of `lens`.

`makeClassy` *also* generates classes named `Has*`, but named after the data type, not the record field, and not following a different pattern.

Your code above generates the following code (shown with `-ddump-splices`):

```hs
    makeLensesWith camelCaseFields ''Env
  ======>
    class HasBalance s a | s -> a where
      balance :: Lens' s a
    instance HasBalance Env (TVar Int) where
      {-# INLINE balance #-}
      balance f_a4eTr (Env x1_a4eTs x2_a4eTt)
        = (fmap (\ y1_a4eTu -> (Env x1_a4eTs) y1_a4eTu)) (f_a4eTr x2_a4eTt)
    class HasLog s a | s -> a where
      log :: Lens' s a
    instance HasLog Env (String -> IO ()) where
      {-# INLINE log #-}
      log f_a4eTx (Env x1_a4eTy x2_a4eTz)
        = (fmap (\ y1_a4eTA -> (Env y1_a4eTA) x2_a4eTz)) (f_a4eTx x1_a4eTy)
```